# Android illegalstateexception in media record

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am working on record media.In following code, there are 2 buttons, one for start record and other for stop it. as soon as I run the code, illegalStateException occured but a file with given name get stored on sd card of emulator.following is the code:

```
    package com.example.try_music;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button btnStart;
private Button btnStop;

File audioFile = null;
MediaRecorder recorder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

}

public void startRecording(View view) throws IllegalStateException, IOException
{
    btnStart.setEnabled(false);
    btnStop.setEnabled(true);

    File fileSample = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    try {
        audioFile = File.createTempFile("my_sound", ".3gp", fileSample);
    } catch (IOException e) {           
        Log.e("myerrortag", "sdcard access error");
    }

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(audioFile.getAbsolutePath());
    recorder.reset();
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
}
public void stopRecording(View view)
{
    btnStart.setEnabled(true);
    btnStop.setEnabled(false);
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
    addRecordingToMediaLibrary();
}

public void addRecordingToMediaLibrary() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "audio"+audioFile.getName());
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int)(current/1000));
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE,"audio/3gpp");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, audioFile.getAbsolutePath());
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Uri uriBase = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Uri newUri  = contentResolver.insert(uriBase, values);

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "added file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
}

}
```

following are the logcat entries:

```
05-27 16:50:49.453: E/AndroidRuntime(23804): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
```

I have added all requisite permission. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: line number which throws exception?

Comment: where do u get illegalStateException on click of a button or when the activity is started?

Comment: `IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity` clearly means you are trying to call Activity methods by creating it's instances. so plz also share where you are calling  `startRecording` and `stopRecording` method's in Activity

Comment: why do you call reset ?

Comment: @Pratik Error is thrown at recorder.start().

Comment: @bakriOnFire illegalstateexception get generated when button is clicked.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK this methods are called in onclick event of buttons.

Comment: @njzk2 reset is called as one of Stack Overflow member suggest me to use it. however code is showing same problem with or without reset.

Comment: @NehaMangla : plz show full code with full logcat results if u are still facing same issue